# Regex Matches Dynamic Number

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex:

```
Regex expD = new Regex("<ns6:userId>(?result>.*?)</ns6:userId>");
```

How can I handle the number `6` changing to any single digit? After software updates, the number may change to `0-9`.

I have tried `\d` and `.` with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you writing this regex? Maybe you need to enter it as a raw string or escape the char classes

Answer (score 2):

If a Regex is constructed from a string, you usually have to escape backslashes, so `\d` would become `\\d`:

```
Regex expD = new Regex("<ns\\d:userId>(?result>.*?)</ns\\d:userId>");
```

You also did not mention any language, which is critical when providing code. I'd say that's Java, but I can't know for sure.

Furthermore, what's `(?...)` supposed to be? ([Debuggex doesn't recognise it](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ylXy6fMk7ihL__55).) Did you mean `(?:...)`, i.e. a non-capturing group?
My guess is you're looking for this:

```
Regex expD = new Regex("<ns\\d:userId>(?:result>.*?)</ns\\d:userId>");
```

But if you say you tried `.` and it didn't work, then either you're using some Regex implementation that is highly incompatible with the rest of the world, or you're applying it wrong.